# Reading and writing client files from a web application

Tags: javascript

I need to implement a mechanism in order for a **remote web application** to communicate with a **local desktop (WinForms) application** that I cannot modify nor have the source of (except by decompiling). This happens by writing a file to the temporary folder that the desktop application will consume, and waiting for that application to "return" by writing another file into `temp` folder. Folder **has to be** temp folder.

#### Question

Is there a Javascript way to access the file system in a non sandboxed way, even by setting specific browser configuration options?

#### Environment

The application runs on a private LAN where all computers trust each other within the same AD domain. Plus we are theoretically allowed to map any network drive on any computer. Working in the trust zone, we don't have to care about **most** security concerns.

#### Background explanation

I have a PowerBuilder desktop application that I need to "port" to web (using J2EE) and install to a **separate** server, local to the same LAN. This application (named `GP`) currently starts a process of the child application (`GC`) that will not show any UI, instead it will listen for two files on a temporary directory.

When GP needs to open a window from the GC process, it will write two files: `GP_to_GC.txt` with a syntax I have documentation of, and `GP_to_GC.flg` that serves as flag file. GC will delete both after retaining and parsing the content of txt file, thus showing the appropriate UI form based on input.

The "return" is exactly the opposite. GC will write a pair of `GC_to_GP` files to temp and GP will refresh its views.

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: You could look into writing a browser specific plugin. I don't think plugins are allowed to access the filesystem etiher, they get a sandboxed filesystem but there's a good chance the sandboxed filesystem is mirrored in the actual filesystem - just like cookies are stored as plaintext in a folder somewhere. You could also consider using cookies but then you're constrained by cookie size limitations which can be really annoying.

Comment: Why can't you just create your own Web app that uses a server side language to interact with the SMB? Or, create a JavaScript front end that calls your custom Web App API, and that API writes to the desktop?

Comment: HTA will let almost-normal webapps reach the file system on window boxes.

Comment: @Halcyon if I write data to cookie the `GC` application, which we cannot modify, won't read anything from Temp. @GeorgeStocker I didn't say I can't create that application, I said the idea sucks. Writing to a remote workstation's filesystem via SMB is a hacky trick. The web server is **remote** to the `GC` application. Let me rephrase

Comment: @dandavis sorry HTA is not viable by design. Application will on server. I admit I was unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I'm reading, you are porting a Desktop based Java EE application to a web application? If so, then you can continue using Java and access the folder that way; no need to use JavaScript.

What is unclear is that you're saying you can't modify anything, yet you're trying to port an application. Which is it?

If you can't modify anything, and the only thing you can do is drop JavaScript into an existing web application, then your solution is rather simple:

Create an HTTP API application that sits somewhere that has access to those folders, and issue a POST request to that API that will then read and write to the file system.  It can be in any server side language you choose: Javascript (Node.js), C#, Java, PHP, whatever.  It simply needs the ability to access the file system through the webserver, and most frameworks provide that capability.

I can't give you any code because you haven't mentioned which server side language you want to use to accomplish this approach.

Comment: Sorry, I must really rephrase. By "porting" I mean we have to **rewrite** a PowerBuilder application, of which we have the source, to a web application based on JSP and Extjs. It simply won't run on the client, but on a central web server. And I think that the localhost server hosting Node is a **great idea** I didn't think about